# Finding the entire length of the cardioid $r = 1-\cos\theta$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find the entire length of the cardioid $r = 1-\cos\theta$.

Although, I'm not sure how to compute the definite integral for $a$ and $b$, given that the equation is for the length of the arc is this:

$$\int^{\theta}_{a}\sqrt{r^2+\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2}\space d\theta$$

Here is my working out:

$\sqrt{(1-\cos\theta)^2-\sin\theta} = 1-2\cos \left(θ\right)+\cos ^2\left(θ\right)-\sin ^2\left(θ\right)$

Hence:

$$\int^{\theta}_{a}\sqrt{\left(\cos \left(θ\right)-1\right)^2-\sin ^2\left(θ\right)}\space d\theta$$

Though, where would I begin with computing the following integral? I appreciate the support.

Comment: The inside of the square root should be - +, not - -

Comment: Fix the sign as per earlier comment, then expand it and it simplifies. You can use $\cos \theta = \cos^2 {(\theta / 2)} - \sin^2 {(\theta / 2)}$.

Comment: @Bernard Aha! That answers my question to (at)user, just in time! Thank you.

Comment: Or even the linearisation formula $\:\sin^2\theta=\dfrac{1−\cos 2\theta}2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the **full** length of the cardioid you need to integrate from $0$ to $2\pi$:
$$
L=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{(1-\cos\theta)^2\color{red}+(\sin\theta)^2}\,d\theta=
\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{2(1-\cos\theta)}\,d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}2\sin\frac\theta2\,d\theta.
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Though, I'm struggling on deriving the identity that led you from $\sqrt{2(1-\cos\theta} = 2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$. Did you perhaps do something like this: $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{(1-\cos\theta)(1+\cos\theta)}=\sqrt{2\sin^2\theta}$. Though, I still cannot figure out how you derived the result. Please show me! I would really like to know.

Comment: The identity is: $1-\cos\theta=2\sin^2\frac\theta2$.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take (due to symmetry with respect to the polar axis) half the integral:

$$L=2\int_0^{\pi}\sqrt{(1-\cos\theta)^2+(\sin\theta)^2}\,d\theta=
4\int_0^{\pi}\sin(\theta/2)\,d\theta=8.$$